# How would I calculate something that someone puts in a input field using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need help with a basic text input field calculator. Where if someone puts 1+1 etc. It will answer the problem in another text input field but I can not figure out how to with my code below any help would be appreciated.

```
function Cal() {
var Num = parseInt(document.getElementById("Numbers").value);
var One = Num;
alert(One);
```

I only have it where it notifys me the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) then you can use a library like [`mathjs`](http://mathjs.org/), or roll your own.

An example of it in use, loaded using [`requirejs`](http://requirejs.org/).

HTML

```
<input id="expression" type="text"></input>
<div id="result">0</div>
```

Javascript

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        mathjs: 'https://raw.github.com/josdejong/mathjs/master/dist/math.min',
    }
});

require(['mathjs'], function (mathjs) {
    var math = mathjs(),
        expression = document.getElementById('expression'),
        result = document.getElementById('result');

    expression.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        result.textContent = math.eval(e.target.value);
    }, false);
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8C4ph/)

Answer (score 2):

You could either write a parser, or use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), presuming they input valid JavaScript arithmetic. This is one of the few cases where it is entirely reasonable to use `eval`, but you still will need to sanitise their inputs.

Comment: But I heard that using eval is bad.

Comment: @CDW: Guns are bad too, but if you are using them for hunting, they are OK. Context matters.

Comment: +1. Really doing eval on value that user *just typed in* is fine (user can as well click F12 and run the same script with dev tools). The issue is when (always :) ) you don't know where the value come in. I.e. what user got mail "paste this string XXXXXXXX and click Calculate" instead of typing themselves? Unfortunately sanitizing input is almost as hard as parsing math expression and you may just write/find expression parser instead. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052470/javascript-parser-for-simple-expression (and similar questions) for links.

Comment: How do you know if the user is not typing in a javascript instead of what is expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` in this situation... something like this could work:

```
function calculateInput(userInput) {
    return eval(string);
}

var userInput = document.getElementById("Numbers").value;

var result = calculateInput(userInput);
alert(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4c6tS/1/