# Javascript If BOOL expression from String

Tags: javascript, boolean, expression

Lets think we have this variables

```
 var x=1;
 var y=2;
 var a = "x>y";
```

is there a way to make something like;

`(if(a){RUN JS CODE;})`

. Because in that way it dont get the boolean expresion (x>y) it will get the bunch of character(the string) I know i can separate:

**the left expression**

**the boolean operator**

**the right expresion**

But that is an extra work to the client side device (because is javascript)

Is there a way to do like "LITERAL STRING" to "Boolean Expresion"

Comment: Where does this string come from? Is this code running in the browser or on the server?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Look up for `eval` - and be aware of consequences.

Comment: Is running in the browser, lets think a user can have certain variables and test any boolean expresion he can make, So he put in the input for example "x>y+2" and the program should show true or false. If they put a correct boolean expression with the correct vars. i mean a valid expression

Comment: Thats the answer isaac and raina and r1verside and obsidian. If i can put correct answer every one deserve it. But it don"t let me because i need wait at least 9 mins more to acept a correct answer. In another way... why eval is "evil"?  if i can be sure it only run a valid boolean expression it should be fine right ?

Comment: I'd avoid using `eval` and go for [a math parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1053534/1377002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an **[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**, which **evaluates** the string to JavaScript code:

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var a = "x > y";

if (eval(a)) {
  console.log('triggered');
}
else {
  console.log('not triggered');
}
```

However, note that `eval()` [can be **evil**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/2341603), as it:

- runs the compiler, which may result in a performance hit
- runs under escalated privileges, leading to possibly vulnerabilities
- inherits the execution context and this binding of the scope in which its invoked

As long as you are aware of these issues, and use `eval()` with caution, you'll be fine to use it.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `if(eval(a))`. I didn't tested it but it's what `eval` does.

To check if the result of the evaluation is a boolean expression you can write

```
if(typeof eval(a) == 'Boolean') {
    console.log("Boolean expression");
}
```

Be aware that the use of `eval` function is highly discouraged.

Douglas Crockford book "JavaScript: The good parts" which I highly recommend to every JavaScript developer, has a chapter on it titled "Eval is Evil" which explains why it is so bad. But just by the title you get an idea.